# Drawing in ArcGIS Engine?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-engine

I am trying to port over a large amount of code for drawing lines, bitmaps (with transparency), and text onto our map display.  Originally it was done using Dynamic Display and `IDynamicMap` but that is no longer possible.

Could anyone tell me the *right* way to go about this without leveraging dynamic layers?

The methods I have tried (`GraphicTracker`) have not been successful and I am new to the ArcGIS Engine API.

Comment: Does each line, bitmap and text have the same transparency, or will it be different?

Comment: Why is it not possible? Graphic trackers can't handle motion. The Docs say to use [DynamicDisplay](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Dynamic_display/0001000003t3000000/). This [guy](http://blog.briannoyle.com/esri-dynamic-displaysome-limitations) got around it but I couldn't figure out how to replicate his work. Sorry this is more of a comment but the comment system doesn't really handle links.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, what I need is alpha-blended bitmaps.

Comment: Graphic Trackers *can* handle motion.  I have a sample with an animated graphic tracker.  But it lacks support for alpha blended bitmaps.

Comment: @tbridge Does it flicker?  When I implemented the example it flickered.

Comment: No, it doesn't flicker.  I have it updating at 20Hz using a WinForms Timer and that seems to work.

Comment: I think you'll need to use GDI+ if you're wanting varying alpha levels.  I did this a few years ago and it was a real pain, especially when updating the UI thread from a background worker.  Have you considered Silverlight/WPF instead?   It sure seems to support animation much better.

Comment: Not an option either at this point.  If I were to use GDI+ how would I do that?  Create a new layer and draw directly to `IActiveView`?

Comment: Actually, as you type a comment, hit the "help" link, which will show how to use "mini-Markdown formatting" for links.

Comment: I'd do it with a custom layer. In your draw method, the IDisplay's hDC can be used with GDI+, google returns a lot of GDI tutorials.  I think the layer needs to be in its own display cache.

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what I was looking for.  Feel free to re-write this as an answer (with even more detail if you want ;-) ) and I will accept it

Comment: @Kirk If you add this as an answer, I will accept it.  This is the method I am using and it is working well for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this with a [custom layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000003v4000000).

In your [draw](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Draw_Method/00120000076p000000/) method, the IDisplay's [hDC](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/hDC_Property/001w000000v9000000/) can be used with [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Google returns a lot of [GDI tutorials](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=gdi++tutorial&aq=f&aqi=g-s2g1g-m1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=951dc7972bfd90fb&biw=1280&bih=572). I think the layer needs to be in its own display cache, which can be achieved by returning true for [ILayer.Cached](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Cached_Property/00120000076n000000/).